# BasicPlayer in new Deezer Android SDK 0.10.16

Tags: android, deezer

I want to use BasicPlayer in new SDK, but the solution from userGuide is not functional.

```
    Player player = new DefaultPlayerFactory(context, deezerConnect,
networkStateChecker).createPlayer();
// a track object fetched from the API
Track track = ... ;
// play a 30 seconds preview
player.init(track.getId(), track.getPreviewUrl());
// play a full track (only for premium users)
player.init(track.getId(), track.getStream());
// Start the player
player.play();
```

The DefaultPlayerFactory is not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, it's an issue that occured with a misconfiguration of proguard on this release, I'll update this for the next version.

The use of the BasicPlayer is not advised, alternatively, you should use a TrackPlayer which provide the same features as the BasicPlayer.

Comment: I want to create own crossfade (fade in/ fade out) functionality and I cannot launch two TrackPlayers in the same time (for some seconds to create crossfade). Player in old SDK could that, but you cannot change volume. Is there any other approach to create a crossfade?

Comment: There's nan issue in the SDK that prevents playing multiple tracks at the same time, that should get corrected in a future version.

Comment: And what about iOS (new beta) and Javascript SDKs. Is it available there or is planned to enable this functionality?